# Compiling and running C++ on Emacs in Windows 7

Tags: c++, emacs, compilation

So, as background, at college I learned how to code python in Emacs in a Linux OS, and while I am at home I downloaded Emacs on my Windows 7, and had a more advanced programmer alter the environment path to a file which is C:\Users\Kimi

I save the .py files I write in Emacs to that Kimi folder, and then create a shell using M-x shell and then run the files using "python example.py"

THIS IS WHAT I AM USED TO SINCE I KNOW PYTHON

however, due to attempting to learn C++, every single tutorial I go to talks about "gcc" and "g++" but no matter how many times I attempt to compile they always say those two terms are not recognized. I think I need to download something, but I have no idea what important things to do in order to have a correct path and stuff because I wish to save all my C++ stuff to C:\Users\Kimi\C++, and be able to compile and run those files smoothly. On Windows 7, of course.

So I am not sure how exactly to go about this. Any kind of helpful instructions would be absolutely wonderful! I am brand spanking new to C++ so being a little detailed would be great, too.

Comment: You might want to have a look at `mingw` http://www.mingw.org/. Also of interest might be something like code::blocks: http://www.codeblocks.org/ I believe the windows installer will also install `mingw` which comes with `gcc`. Ultimately windows might just not be the best platform to do what you want.

Comment: Thats what I've been seeing a lot from other people, I just don't have the resources to change to Linux. I don't want to do that to my computer since its sort of reaching middle age. I'm looking at Visual C++ Express so maybe I can play around with that. I just want to be able to learn and practice before classes start again.

Comment: ` I don't want to do that to my computer since its sort of reaching middle age` specifically what do you think will go wrong? You can always dual-boot if you don't want to get rid of windows.

Comment: Eh, you're absolutely right. I can't really think of what could go wrong, maybe I'm just so used to Windows right now. But changing to Linux would probably really help me in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

Download and install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).  The world will make sense agian :)

Comment: Out of votes currently, but this is a good advice - be sure to select the developer tools in *cygwin* setup.